# How to pass data from form in Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.textboxfor

I want to pass value TextBoxFor to my update action but I don't get it how to do. I know I have to pass somewhere maybe like this... new { $id = "Status"}.
I have to buttons one for Increase and one for Decrease.. But the main problem is to pass a value of Textbox to my action ..
Here is my InventoryUpdateDto class and Action

```
public class InventoryUpdateDto 
    {
        public int InvId { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Status must be numbers")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }

[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Increase(InventoryUpdateDto inventory)
        {
             using (context)
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
                    var prRecord = await context.Inventories.FindAsync(inventory.InvId);
                    prRecord.Status = prRecord.Status + inventory.Status;
                    context.Inventories.Add(prRecord);
                    context.Entry(prRecord).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    SllitHub.NotifyCurrentInformationToAllClients();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

         }
```

And my form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.InvId)

            <div class="well well-sm col-lg-6">
                // How can I send value of this TextBox value to my action?
                // I tried but could not update
                @Html.TextBox("Status", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                // This one is better I can Update but it's not empty textbox
                @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Status, new { @class = "form-control" })*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status)

                <input type="submit" name="response" value="Increase" formaction=@Url.Action("Increase", "Home") formmethod="post"/>
                <input type="submit" name="response" value="Decrease" formaction=@Url.Action("Decrease", "Home") formmethod="post"/>
            </div>

        }
```

I tried like this too

```
@Html.TextBox("Status", null, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Status" })
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If your `InventoryUpdateDto` has a `Status` property, when you submit the fform with name `Status` , model binding will map the posted value. You might also use the `TextBoxFor`

Comment: @Shyju , Yes I have as you see now in my code, but my textBox value sends empty ....to my action.

Comment: Is the `Status` property settable ?

Comment: @Shyju Yes. This following working but I don't want to see what I have already in my database. I want empty field then when make some input then I want to make update.. ...Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Status, new { ...class = "form-control" }) .

Comment: You can add `@Html.TextBox("NewStatus")` and add a new parameter to the httppost action method called `newStatus` and when the form is submitted, the input value will be mapped to that paramter

Comment: @Shyju I tried like this <input type="submit" name="response" value="Increase" formaction=...Url.Action("Increase", "Home", new { ..id = "NewStatus"}) formmethod="post"/>  but not workin. It send an empty value. Please show me by writing farther what do you mean if you don't mind. I do like this becouse I have two buttons.

Comment: what specifically is not working ? Is it making an HttpPost call to your `Increase` action method  ? What value is empty  and what is your expected value ?

Comment: @Shyju it's passing ziro value. Is this the right way to code?  <input type="submit" name="response" value="Increase" formaction=...Url.Action("Increase", "Home", new { ..id = "NewStatus"})  and please let me see your full code, I Think I'am coding in wrong way.

Comment: are you entering a non zero value to the `NewStatus` textbox inside the form ?

Comment: @Shyju If I write 5 and run bugging I see 0 (ziro) ...I Think I'am not passing in the right way... please just look at my code if it's right. <input type="submit" name="response" value="Increase" formaction=...Url.Action("Increase", "Home", new { ..id = "NewStatus"})

Comment: not sure why you have `.id = "NewStatus"` ! your form already has an element with name `NewStatus`, and the form submit will send the data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160651/discussion-between-helen-tekie-and-shyju).

Comment: @Shyju you wrote Before "add a new parameter to the httppost action method called newStatus" .. thatway I did. Let us continue in chatt

Comment: Your code is not really making sense and its unclear what your trying to do. If all you want if to click the 'Increase' button and have the existing value of `Status` incremented by one (say from 4 to 5) and de-increment the value if you click the `Decrease' button, then your going about this the wrong way

Comment: Or are you wanting to increase (or decrease) the value based on what the user enters in the textbox?

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you. Yes I want to increase (or decrease) the value based on what the user enters in the textbox

Comment: The code you have shown will form fine. If you enter say 2 in the textbox, then the value of `inventory.Status` will be `2` (using either the preferred `TextBoxFor()` or the `TextBox()` method). If its not working for you then it due to something you have not shown us.

Comment: But you do not do `return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);` is `ModelState` is invalid. You return the view so that the user can correct the error.

Comment: And your `context.Inventories.Add(prRecord);` code does not make sense since that record already exists (surely you just want to update the existing record)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I only have on the top of the BeginForm @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.InvId). If I use this Html.EditorFor(model => model.Status, null, new { htmlAttributes = new { ..class = "form-control" } })    with my button <input type="submit" name="response" value="Increase" formaction=..Url.Action"Increase", "Home") formmethod="post"/> Then it works. But I want an empty textbox. So With TextBoxFor.. it's working But not with TextBox. So you mean I do not need to pass value of textbox as parameter?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand - your code shows that you also have `@Html.TextBox("Status")` (but you should be using `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Status)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Status) shows me even what I have alraedy in my database , but works fine. What I want was an empty textbox. But I Think I have to pass the value maybe as parameter.. but I dot know how

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160841/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-helen-tekie).